# Web service fails until the URL is hit with IE

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, webservices-client

We have a WinForms application (.NET 4.0/C#) that accesses several web services.  We deployed to a client who has some proxy feature on their firewall (no proxy settings in Internet Options on the client machine, but it definitely IS a proxy).

The problem is, our WinForms app will fail on the first web service call.  The error information isn't very useful but it's clear that it's unable to call the web service methods.  The weird part is, once we put the web service (asmx) URL in Internet Explorer on that client machine, it works just fine for several days.  It's as if IE is causing the router to cache some of the routing information.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a simple fix that we could implement?

Thank you!

Here is the Exception information:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.WebException
Stack:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at     AutoUpdater.Module.WebService.AutoUpdaterWebService.AutoUpdater.ValidateInstallKey(String installKey, String computerIdentifier)
   at AutoUpdater.Module.WebService.Config.ValidateInstallKey()
   at AutoUpdater.Module.RemoteService.ValidateInstallKey()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32)
   at AutoUpdater.Foundation.Interfaces.IRemoteService.ValidateInstallKey()
   at AutoUpdater.UpdateForm..ctor()
   at AutoUpdater.Program.Main()
```

Comment: What's the WebException?

Comment: can you show the code of web service call?

Comment: Im thinking that IE is set to automatically detect the proxy. Once you get the proxy configure on the client by ie, your ok after that.

Comment: @UnhandledException the code is pretty basic:

    using (AutoUpdaterWebService.AutoUpdater service = new AutoUpdaterWebService.AutoUpdater())
    {
    return service.ValidateInstallKey(_installKey, "");
    }

Comment: @user957902 that seems to be just about right, except it will start working for the entire network for about 30 days once one person visits that URL in IE.  Is there some sort of Group Policy or something that could be controlling this?